# Connected graph definition

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

It is correct to say that a connected graph is only when there exist some vertex that is connected to all other vertices?

I think this is correct, because a connected graph not all vertices are connected together, but at least no vertex is not connected? Isn't that the above definition is saying?

I know the standard definition but I want to know if this definition is also correct. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "vertex $u$ is 'connected' to vertex $v$"? Do you mean that there is a **path** from $u$ to $v$? Or do you mean that $u$ and $v$ are joined by an **edge** of the graph?

Comment: I mean that in all graphs there is some vertex that is connected to (all) other vertices.

Comment: My question was, what does "connected to" mean?

Comment: That there is an edge between two vertices.

Comment: That's what I was afraid you meant. In standard terminology, $u$ is **joined** (or **adjacent**) to $v$ if there is an edge $uv$; they are **connected** if there is a **path** (possibly containing many edges) from $u$ to $v$. Consider the connected graph with $5$ vertices $u,v,w,x,y$ and $4$ edges $uv,vw,wx,xy$. The vertex $u$ is **joined** only to $v$, but it's **connected** to all the other vertices; it's connected to $y$ by the **path** $u,uv,v,vw,w,wx,x,xy,y$.

Comment: so the definition is still correct?

Comment: The part where you say "a connected graph not all vertices are connected together" is nonsense. Unless by "connected" you meant "joined by an edge"; but under **that** interpretation, the definition in your first sentence is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. A graph is connected if and only if for all $x, y \in V(G)$, there exists a path from $x$ to $y$.

When talking about directed graphs, we have the concepts of weak connectivity vs. strong connectivity. In a weakly connected graph, we are guaranteed either a directed $x-y$ path or a  directed $y-x$ path, but not necessarily both. A strongly connected path guarantees us both a directed $x-y$ path and a directed $y-x$ path.

Comment: Thank you. So the above definition it is correct?

Comment: It is correct, but the universal quantifier strengthens the definition and reduces ambiguity.

Comment: We haven't told about the strong connectivity so we suppose that the definition is describing the plain connectivity?

Comment: This is the definition I'd use. It's a more exacting and stronger definition than the one you gave, no offense: "A graph is connected if and only if for all $x,y \in V(G)$, there exists a path from x to y."

Comment: @ml0105 Can we also say a graph is connected if there exists a walk between any 2 vertices ? Why are we emphasising on path ?

Comment: There exists a $u-v$ walk if and only if there exists a $u-v$ path in your graphs, where $u, v$ are vertices. So your observation is correct. Paths don’t have repeated vertices, which make them easier to work with than walks in certain proofs.